# How to get specified line in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtextarea

I would like to write the content of `JTextArea` into the `.txt` file but I do not want to loose new line characters. So I want to write it line by line I do not know how to get specified line from the `JTextArea`.

Comment: `getText()` returns the whole text, including newline characters of course. Write this whole text to the file, and you're done. Why would you need to write line by line?

Comment: The JTextArea can do all this for you via its write method. Simply pass in a BufferedWriter that outputs to your file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `JtextArea`'s `write` method to do this

```
 JTextArea jArea=new JTextArea();
 //do something............
 BufferedWriter fileOut = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(yourFile));
 jArea.write(fileOut);
```

Comment: This is the better approach. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I used different approach but this is better.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I used:

```
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));                   
                    String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator");
                    String text = jta.getText() ;
                    String as = text.replaceAll("\n", ln);
                    bw.write(as.toString(),0, as.length());
                    bw.close();
```

but the accepted answer is better.